# Trying to make like button with parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath function I created this so that it will append the amount of likes for every single post, but for some reason it crashes. Does anyone know why?

```
var postQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")
    postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                    self.likesArray.append((object["likers"] as! [String]).count)

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unwrap the optional....

```
var postQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")
postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
    if (objects != nil) {
        for object in objects! {
            self.likesArray.append((object["likers"] as! [String]).count)
        }
    }
}
```

Please try this and tell me if it solved your problem